# Delete the vertex of a line in Carto Builder

Tags: carto

How can I delete the vertex of a line that I have previously created?
I´m doing tests. I know how to edit a line or create a new one and add vertexs clicking in a transparent circle between two vertexs already created, but if i want to remove this vertex created, i don´t know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! A good question should show some degree of research and attempt.  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to expand on the problem and outline what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

The builder interface for editing geometries is very tedious and rigid. Let me explain by using the posted instructions.

Step 1, go to the dataset view: If you have one geometry in your set, that's fine, but if the majority is as I imagine, and has thousands of geometries (I have just under 10,000 in my primary set), then you will be wasting an obscene amount of time scrolling through to locate that geometry.

Step 2, remove the vertex: Let's say you decided to scroll through hundreds of records to locate the one in question. You then have a polygon whose vertices are probably quite close to each other and include up to 8 decimal places. The only way to be sure which vertex is which is by deleting them one by one until you get the right one. Absolutely ridiculous.

By the way, if you try to bypass the hundred-geometry scroll to in step 1 by using SQL to filter your results, you can no longer edit the values in the each field, so don't bother with that either.

Although you can still add new vertices on the map by dragging the center 'inactive' vertices, the ability to right click on an existing vertex to delete it has been removed for I have no idea what reason.

I understand that the Builder has only recently been released and will be updated, but it has some major deficiencies that would have driven me away if I was just now looking researching a new tool to use. Having invested time, money, and infrastructure in Carto 4-5 years ago, I am kind of bound here still. Hopefully if I just wait it out, some much needed improvements will come along.

Answer (score 0):

In BUILDER, you can remove a line vertex editing `the_geom` field from the dataset. Let's say you have a line with three vertexes:

[image: builder-line]

Go to the dataset view (clicking on the small blue button at the bottom right corner that looks like a table). Double click on `the_geom` cell you want to edit (it should say `Line`).

[image: table-editing]

Then remove the vertex coordinates array and click enter. Voilá!

[image: vertex-removed]