# How can I delete polygon nodes in Carto Builder?

Tags: carto, editing

Editing a polygon is possible by clicking on it, and the edit "pencil" icon appears, allowing you to drag or even add new coordinates. There is, however, no way to delete coordinates, as far as I can tell, except by doing an update function using SQL and manually finding and typing in the lat-long coordinates. That would be immensely tedious, since the coordinates' locations in my map are based on visual appearance rather than any quantitative relationship.

Comment: A question similar to this one was already answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231438/delete-the-vertex-of-a-line-in-carto-builder